# INSERT if VALUES don't exists

Tags: php, mysql

I have been loosing my MIND with this. I have three tables that I have to join, but I need to insert into the database only IF the three columns do not have existing values. I have tried `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, `WHERE NOT EXISTS`, and FINALLY and am trying `INSERT IGNORE` that last one is a result of nothing where as the others would insert even IF the same values existed.

I am trying to

```
insert into TABLE name: set_colors (school_art_id, baseimage_id, sub_folder, layer)
```

`school_art_id` is from "id" another table called `school_art`
`baseimage_id` is the "id" from a table called `baseimage`
`sub_folder` is the folder name in `baseimage.sub_folder`
layer is the value from `baseimage.layer`

This is the query that DOES NOT work

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO set_colors (school_art_id, baseimage_id, sub_folder, layer)
SELECT 'school_art.id', 'baseimage.id', 'baseimage.sub_folder', 'baseimage.layer' 
SET school_art_id='school_art.id', 
baseimage_id='baseimage.id', 
sub_folder='baseimage.sub_folder', 
layer=baseimage.layer
```

Can someone please tell me what am I doing WRONG here?

Answer (score 2):

Your query syntax is completely broken for the select portion. You're selecting a series of constant strings, and then for some reason break into 'SET' and do some assignments. This makes no sense whatsoever, since you don't SET a value in a select.

Your query should look something like

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO set_colors (school_art_id, baseimage_id, sub_folder, layer)
SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4
FROM some_other_table
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 INSERT IGNORE
```

should be

```
 INSERT IGNORE INTO
```

however `SET` isn't possible to be used in SELECT or in INSERT INTO query

Comment: Thank you and I got ALL excited, but it is still not working, any other ideas?

Comment: Learn how [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) statement should look like

Comment: actually it IS possible to use SET with INSERT INTO

Comment: Not in the form SELECT {fields} SET... it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the solution, in case anyone else comes across the same problem ( I put this in a class so the {$value} is just passed in when you call the class.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO set_colors (school_art_id, baseimage_id, sub_folder, layer)
SELECT school_art.id, baseimage.id, baseimage.sub_folder, baseimage.layer
FROM school_art 
JOIN baseimage ON baseimage.base_folder = school_art.series_code 
WHERE baseimage.image_type = 'B' AND school_art.id = '{$value}' ORDER BY school_art.id"
```